# Can I travel without a visa by boat from Dubai to Ireland?

Tags: visas, sea-travel, ireland, visa-free-entry, iraqi-citizens

Can I travel by boat from Dubai to Ireland without first obtaining an Irish visa?

And I have another question which is what am I required to have with me if am traveling by a plane from Dubai to Ireland, as a 14 year old girl with an Iraqi passport?

Comment: Do you intend to enter Ireland?

Comment: I am not aware of any country in the world whose visa rules depend on whether you are entering the country by boat, plane, car, or on foot. There are some exemptions for people who are just changing planes in a country, and some exemptions for crew on a boat who don't intend to come ashore, but just the fact of traveling there by boat instead of plane should not make any difference for you.

Comment: Some countries have stricter entry requirements for people not entering on scheduled transport, not sure about Ireland, but you can sometimes need visas to arrive by private boat or plane when scheduled plane or ferry wouldn't

Comment: @KateGregory: There are places that give limited visa free entry if landing only at particular airports, I think China does this. And there are places that give a different duration of stay depending on whether you arrive by air or land, Thailand does this. But yes nothing I know of that's relevant to this question.

Comment: @KateGregory Can't find the answer where it was discussed on this site but: [Russia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Russia#Cruise_ship_passengers) has a slightly different policy depending on the port and method of entry.

Comment: When entering Singapore by boat, train or bus, you get a 15 day free "visa", if you fly in, you get 30 days.

Comment: @KateGregory NZ citizens enter Australia without a visa by plane, but require a visa if arriving by boat (legacy law) :(

Comment: @user9855: You just asked a few days ago in another question if you need a visa for Ireland. I assume you are an Iraqi citizen, in which case you need a visa both for entering and transiting Ireland, no matter if you get there by plane or boat.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Technically you might be able to get away with staying on the boat the whole time while it's in the port in Ireland.  Though I don't see the point.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a visa when flying, you will also need a visa when arriving on a boat.

In most cases, it does not matter at all how you enter the country. While there are exceptions, as the comments suggest, these are usually only to make things easier or harder for common cases.
Minor Iraqis travelling from UAE to Ireland on a boat are surely not that common, so there won't be any special rules for it ;)

Comment: Welcome! It's best to answer a question with evidence if possible, like a link to an embassy site showing the requirement for a visa...